# Laravel auditing: change the default table name "audits"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-auditing

Since we are using the audits table already in our project, is there any way to change the table name from "`audits`" to like "`audit_trail_histories`"?

Comment: There isn't a default Laravel table that is named "audits", unless you're talking about a package?

Comment: we are using the audit (model) therefore, we are using the audits table. since it will be a duplicate of our table (model), i need to change the default table name of Laravel Auditing

Comment: @GemilAguinaldo When using a third-party package, it's generally best to include a link to it so people know which one you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `up()` and `down()` methods in the migration file, so that `audit_trail_histories` is set as the table name.

```
// ...

Schema::create('audit_trail_histories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // ...
});

// ...

Schema::drop('audit_trail_histories');

// ...
```

Execute `php artisan migrate` to create the table.

Update the configuration like so:

```
return [
    // ...

    'drivers' => [
        'database' => [
            'table' => 'audit_trail_histories',
            // ...
        ],
    ],

    // ...
];
```

That's it!

Comment: oh i see, i need to manually edit the migration file. thanks man for the info!

Comment: one problem, since i already have a Audit model, it conflicts with the Audit model of laravel-auditing. im trying to migrate to ventureCraft/revisionable. wish me luck!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/4.1/general-configuration

> The Database driver allows modifying:
>
> - The database connection.
> - The table where the Audit records are stored.

.

> ```
> return [
>     // ...
>     'drivers' => [
>         'database' => [
>             'table'      => 'audits',
>             'connection' => null,
>         ],
>     ],
>     // ...
> ];
> ```

Comment: have edited that already, when performing the "php artisan vendor:publish --provider "OwenIt\Auditing\AuditingServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"", it still uses the "audits" table

Comment: Chances are you need to re-publish the migrations (and remove the old ones) after editing `config/audit.php`. If it still doesn't work, file a bug report in their Github.